# How do I insert data into multiple partitioned Hive Table with multiple Spark jobs simultaneously and avoid InsertOperationConflictException?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

I'd like to upload several CSVs into an existing Hive table using several parallel Spark jobs. Each CSV goes into a single partition, and each job would upload one CSV. How do I do this?

### Details:

I have a Hive table that is partitioned on a field `date` and `ptn`. I need upload 10 CSV files daily into this table, one into each partition `ptn` for a given day. To this, I've written a spark job that accepts arguments passed via the command line and then does the following:

```py
[... stuff related to the schema, formatting, and argparse ...]
(
        spark.read
        .option("header", False)
        .csv(args.file, schema=schema)
        .select(
            [...],
            functions.lit(str(datetime.date.today())).alias("date"),
            functions.lit(args.partition).alias("ptn"),

        )
        .write
        .partitionBy("date", "ptn")
        .mode('append')
        .saveAsTable(args.table)
    )
 )
```

I then run this job via spark submit. When I try to run multiple jobs in parallel usually a few complete, but there are issues

- I'll get `InsertOperationConflictException: Failed to hold insert operation lock, another operation of application_ABCD has holden the insert operation lock under viewfs://apollo-rno/user/hive...`
- Sometimes the table gets corrupted and subsequent Spark SQL queries will fail with information about missing partitions.
- Is it related to the dynamic partitioning? If I were to specify the specific partitions statically, would this be an issue. How do you do this?
- I've tried running with and without the flag `--conf spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic`

Running the jobs one-at-a-time successfully inserts the data. I'll adopt this as the fix if there is no other way. I'd prefer not to as I'll need to add code to cause the jobs to run sequentially.

Comment: Try to remove `partitionBy` and use `insertInto` instead of `saveAsTable`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get a similar error.
Code: `.write.mode('append').insertInto(args.table)`

Error: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o185.insertInto: org.apache.spark.InsertOperationConflictException: Failed to hold insert operation lock...`

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

I think there is an issue with how you want to do this.  Why not give all the files to one job and give it all the executors it would use in the multitude of jobs?  Spark was designed to parallelize the work so *you* don't have to think about parrelization.  I respectfully suggest that you use one job to complete all the work and throw as many executors at it that make sense.

Is the cvs file sufficiently large to warrant multiple executors reading it? (What's your [block size](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Data_Blocks)? what's the average file size?)  If the files are small you might actually get more speed concatenating these files together to optimize your read by decreasing wasted reads. HDFS reads the entire block regardless if it's full or not.

If you insist on using multiple jobs at the same time, (Which again I don't suggest.) you may want to look at doing manual file movement and using `MSCK REPAIR TABLE [table name]`

Essentially:
Each job builds its own table.(will call this [job tables].
You write code to move files via hdfs (From job tables) into the partitioned folders of the target table.
You run  `MSCK REPAIR TABLE [table name]` to let hive know that there are new partitions in HDFS that it needs to become aware of.

Or

You create a `view` that `union`s the "jobs tables" and the "target tables".  This would give you close to instant access to the data.
Then you write another script that runs to migrates all the data from the job tables to the target tables that runs in down time, daily or weekly.  It doesn't delete the tables, just migrates data, and if you always use the view anyone using the table will never have to know the implementation details.